Evaluating Javascript in WebView through Jetpack Compose IconButton
I am writing my first Android app and after lots of trial and error I've managed to get a working scaffold structure with a top bar, bottom bar, and webview. What I'm trying to do now is make is so the buttons I've added to the bottom bar can execute Javascript inside the Webview. As of right now, the page correctly loads but clicking
IconButton(onClick = {    webView.evaluateJavascript("console.log('Hello World');", null)  })
does not do anything. I'm aware that it's probably something to do with the webView variable not being properly defined but I can't figure out how to fix it. I've spent the past hour troubleshooting this code with no luck, any help would be much appreciated!
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            PDFJSTheme {
                MainContent()
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled", "UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainContent() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
                    titleContentColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text("PDF.js")
                },
                actions = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.MoreVert,
                        contentDescription = "image"
                    )
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                actions = {
                    /* Freehand Highlighter */
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        webView.evaluateJavascript("console.log('Hello World');", null)
                    }) {
                        Icon(painterResource(id = R.drawable.sharp_ink_highlighter_24), contentDescription = "Localized description")
                    }
                    /* Text Highlighter */
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Default.TextFormat,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description",
                        )
                    }
                    /* Draw  */
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Default.Draw,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description",
                        )
                    }
                    /* Eraser */
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                        Icon(painterResource(id = R.drawable.sharp_ink_eraser_24), contentDescription = "Localized description")
                    }
                    /* Add Image */
                    IconButton(onClick = { /* do something */ }) {
                        Icon(
                            Icons.Default.Image,
                            contentDescription = "Localized description",
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(innerPadding),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
        ) {
            MyWebView()
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun MyWebView() {
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                webViewClient = WebViewClient()
                WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
                settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                settings.useWideViewPort = true
                settings.allowFileAccess = true
                settings.mixedContentMode = MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
                settings.allowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true
                settings.allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true
            }
        },
        update = { webView ->
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web/viewer.html")
        }
    )
}

Clicking the Freehand Highlighter Icon Button should trigger a console.log event, but nothing appears. I have watched the console in a remote Chromium window.

Welcome to stackoverflow! If you found an answer useful, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark button at the left side of an answer.

I don't see where you have declared the webView variable for this line:
webView.evaluateJavascript("/*...*/")

I am assuming that you have a variable in your file somewhere, but that is not a recommended approach. Instead, try to pass a String down to your WebView that contains the JavaScript that the WebView should execute. Then, once that String is non-empty, execute the JavaScript in the update function.
Please try the following code:
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Composable
fun MyWebView(javascriptString: String, onJavaScriptPerformed: () -> Unit) {

    var initialLoading by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            WebView(context).apply {
                //...
            }
        },
        update = { webView ->
            // if our JavaScript modifies the web page, 
            // we want to load the web page only at the first time, 
            // otherwise our changes will always be overwritten
            if (initialLoading) {
                webView.loadUrl("https://dl.google.com/")  // sample webpage
                initialLoading = false
            }
            if (javascriptString.isNotBlank()) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript(javascriptString, null)
                onJavaScriptPerformed()
            }
        }
    )
}

Then, in your parent Composable, call the MyWebView Composable like this:
@Composable
fun MainContent() {

    var javascriptString by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            //...
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                actions = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = {
                            // sample JavaScript to modify webpage
                            javascriptString = "document.documentElement.innerHTML = '<h1>Button A clicked</h1>'";  
                        }
                    ) {
                        //...
                    }
                    //...
                }
            )
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            //...
        ) {
            MyWebView(
                javascriptString = javascriptString,
                onJavaScriptSucces = {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Javascript was executed")
                    javascriptString = ""
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

According to the documentation, the WebView will execute the update function when it is initially inflated and then whenever a state variable used in the update block is changed.
update = { view ->

    // View's been inflated or state read in this block has been updated
    // As selectedItem is read here, AndroidView will recompose
    // whenever the state changes
    // Example of Compose -> View communication
    view.selectedItem = selectedItem
}

Output before and after pressing IconButton
 | 
